# $& not resolved as part of perl substitution

Tags: regex, perl

I have a perl script which searches and replaces data in multiple files. Since more than one word can be replaced in a file, I wrote a function that accepts the search and replace patterns as arrays. I then loop over the arrays in this function and perform the substitution. It works well but just for one particular file, I need to append something in front of the matched string( character #). Hence, I pass "#\$&" as my replace pattern. Its received properly but somehow the $& is never resolved. Instead the operation replaces the matched string with literal value of '#$&'. The same thing works if I directly use #$& in my substituion command in the readFile function. I know we may be able to achieve the result in other ways, but I really want to know why the same replacement pattern works when passed directly while it doesn't work when read as an array element. 
I have commented the substitution command that works well for reference. Can anyone please help me spot the problem here ?

```
my @search= ("host\\s*(replication|all)");
my @replace= ("#\$&");

my $sLine = scalar @search;
my $rLine = scalar @replace;

my $data = ???;

for ( my $i=0; $i < $sLine; $i++)
{
     print("\n search = $search[$i]  replace = $replace[$i] \n");
     #$data =~ s/$search[$i]/#$&/g; ==> this works
     $data =~ s/$search[$i]/$replace[$i]/g; #==> this doesn't
}

print($data);
```

Comment: You're replacing the matched string with the string held in `$replace[$i]`. That string is not itself evaluated.

Comment: There is global performance penalty for using $& in old (below 5.020) interpreter versions. Please read perldoc perlfaq6 and perldoc perlvar.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the working solution and the non-working solution is the same as the difference between

```
print "#$&";              # Prints `#` and the value of `$&`.
```

and

```
print "$replace[$i]";     # Prints the value of `$replace[$i]`.
```

You can use the following:

```
use String::Substitution qw( gsub_modify );

for my $i (0..$#search) {
   gsub_modify($data, $search[$i], $replace[$i]);
}
```

---

This is a more in-depth explanation.

```
s/$search[$i]/#$&/g
```

is short for

```
s/$search[$i]/  "#$&"   /eg
```

which is equivalent to

```
s/$search[$i]/  "#" . $&   /eg    # Replaces with `#` and the value of `$&`.
```

`/e` causes the replacement expression to be evaluated as Perl code, using its result as the replacement string.

On the other hand,

```
s/$search[$i]/$replace[$i]/g
```

is short for

```
s/$search[$i]/  "$replace[$i]"   /eg
```

which is equivalent to

```
s/$search[$i]/  $replace[$i]   /eg    # Replaces with the value of `$replace[$i]`.
```

Comment: @Dada, Contrary to what you said, your solution is very much subject to code injection. For example, try with `my @search = '.*'; my @replace = '".print("owned\n")."'; $_ = '';` (Of course, that's a malicious code injection, but the code fails if `"` contained in the replace expression even non-maliciously.)

Comment: Yes, yes, but I meant that with his replacement, there is nothing to fear. I initially wrote a paragraph warning against such vulnerabilities, but since his example is safe, I ruled against it. However, I realize that it's not a good thing to have answers on SO suggesting to use /ee since people less aware might use it without being cautious enough, which is why I deleted my answer. Thx for you comments though; I think you are right to advise against suggesting to use /ee ;)

Comment: @Dada, If you truly believed that the replacement expression was fixed, you would have recommended `s/$search[$i]/#$&/g`

Comment: Obviously not fixed, but it does not have to be `".exec("cat /etc/passwd && rm -rf /")."`... Looked more like some regular strings with `$&` appearing somewhere...

Comment: @Dada, Nope but it could be. Or it could even be something as simple as `"$&"` or even `a "b" c`. All of these would fail because of the code injection bug in that solution.